# How to sort Map<Integer, MyClass> by a property of MyClass?

Tags: android, json, dictionary

I am using GSON to deserialize JSON like this:

```java
Type mapType = new TypeToken<Map<Integer, MyClass> >() {}.getType(); // define generic type
Map<Integer, MyClass> jsData= gson.fromJson(r, mapType);
```

`MyClass` is:

```java
public class MyClass{
    private String status;  
    private String mObjectType; //Where mObjectType = Type1 = Type2 = Type3 = Type4
    //some more value + getters/setters
}
```

JSON response is:

```
{
  128: {
    status: someValue,
    mObjectType: Type1
  },
  124: {
    status: someValue,
    mObjectType: Type3
  },
  123: {
    status: someValue,
    mObjectType: Type2
  }
}
```

Thereafter I have `Map` with JSON data and I can iterate through `Map`. I want sort this `Map` by value `mObjectType` for insert into `ListAdepter` in a certain order, there ObjectType will be header each section.

How can I sort this map on `mObjectType`? Through iterator I can get all of values for current key. Or will it be better implement a custom `Comparator`?

**upd**

I did it like:

```
Iterator i = jsData.entrySet().iterator();
    while (i.hasNext()){
        Map.Entry iLookObj = (Map.Entry)i.next();
        MyClass temp = (MyClass)iWatchObj.getValue();
        if(temp.getObjectType().equals("ObjectType1")){
            ObjectType1.add(temp);
        } else if (temp.getObjectType().equals("ObjectType2")){
            ObjectType2.add(temp);
        }else if (temp.getObjectType().equals("ObjectType3")){
            ObjectType3.add(temp);
        }   
    }
```

Do not know yet how differently do it.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to sort a Map<Key, Value> on the values in Java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/109383/how-to-sort-a-mapkey-value-on-the-values-in-java)

Comment: Double is simple. If i will compare MyClass objects, i don think what they sorted how i want. I did it like in update.

Comment: Just compare on the desired `MyClass`' property? Cast both `Object`s inside `compare()` to `MyClass`, get the desired property and compare on it.

Comment: I have a problem with the optimal code, but what's the difference in speed will be? Only in memory allocation, i'm wrong? Good advice would be great. Thanks a lot.